# fetch() method error "Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON"

Tags: node.js, fetch, google-api-nodejs-client

i trying to send request to Google HSM API to generate the CSR using the below method

```
const response = await fetch(`https://cloudkms.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${projectId}/locations/${locationId}/keyRings/my-key-ring/cryptoKeys/${keyId}:createCertificateSigningRequest`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    });
```

when i try to parse response body using the code below. i get "Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON" error.

```
const responseBody = response.json();
const csrPem = responseBody.pemCsr;
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: The response is HTML instead of the expected JSON. Check the status code of the response; I think it is not 200 but in the range of 4xx (client error), meaning that your request is missing something.

Comment: yes. the status code is 404.

Comment: Well, that is pretty self-explanatory, isn't it? You are asking for a resource that does not exist.